# How to render a template in a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, template-engine, laravel-blade

I have a blade template called 'main' and I wonder how I can render a sub template by calling a controllers method in my main template. Lets say I have a Controller `WidgetsController` with a method `getSubView`. The method returns a specific view with some data from (for instance) a database.

I already tried to `@include` a template but this will not call the controller which sets some necessary data to the view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't entirely understand your question.

I think what you are looking for is a [View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers)

It allows you to get data for a subview without having to create the data in every controller.

Answer (score 1):

views don't call services, they only take variables and put them on screen for presentation.

you're on the good side with `@include()`. you only need to gather the infos for that sub view beforehand in the controller, and pass it to the `View::make('main')->with($vars)`.

you may also consider using another `<?= View::make('subview')->with($vars->sub);?>` within the the view. or just use the [@extend](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#extending-blade) functionality.